# How to store login information using flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I store login information using flutter?
I'm trying to create two pages login page and home page.
once the user logged in I want to store the information so next time they run the application they automatically redirect to the home page.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried in order to help you better.

Comment: @MarcEstrada its not necessary to always put a code when you ask for a help i only need some information, like the guy who answered below anyway thanks for checking.

Comment: In my opinion, if no code is needed, I think you could search harder. Typing in Google "store persistent information flutter" the first link which appears gives you the solution: https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/key-value/. So your question is not useful in Stack Overflow. And this is why I downvoted.

Comment: noted thanks for the info. ill do it next time.

Comment: @MarcEstrada, not a reason to downvote, the best practice to persist generic data is not the best practice to store login data (security-wise). BTW this question is now #1 result for `flutter store session info` (in google)

Comment: @marc estrada, i think this is a very good question to ask, there is a time someone needs opinions from experts!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Remember that something like login information is "Sensitive information!" and should be stored securely! Shared preferences might not be a good idea to store sensitive data!
So you can use the [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_secure_storage#-installing-tab-) to store login data!

Just for note:

flutter_secure_storage
A Flutter plugin to store data in secure storage:

Keychain is used for iOS
AES encryption is used for Android. AES secret key is encrypted with RSA and RSA key is stored in KeyStore
Note KeyStore was introduced in Android 4.3 (API level 18). The plugin wouldn't work for earlier versions.

Comment: this is the correct answer. passwords should never be in plaintext, even for the client side

Answer (score -3):

You can use [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences)

Example from plugin page:

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
```

Just apply the same idea to save data that you require

Comment: will this work even when the application is force or the phone it turned off. ? ill try it and ill get back to you! thank you!

Comment: yes as the Shared Preferences are stored as application data in your smartphone.  Of course, if you delete the application data or remove the application, it will disappear.

Comment: SharedPreferences on Android and iOS (NSUserDefaults) are not secure. The recommended approach is to use keychains, see the accepted answer.